# What's a good API for recording/capturing and playing back sound in Delphi and/or C#?

Tags: c#, delphi, desktop-application

*<flavor> I want to create a spelling test program for my grade schoolers that would let them enter and record their spelling words then test them on them through out the week.</flavor>*

What's a good Delphi API with which I could select a recording device, capture and save sound files, then play them back?

I'm also toying with doing the same project in C#, so C# Sound capture/playback API recommendations would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to recording would be to use the MS Speech API with C#, enter the words via keyboard, and have it state what was keyed in.

Just a thought...  Good luck on your app -- it sounds like a really cool program!

Comment: I'll play with that, my concern is that it probably will mangle a few of the words via phonetic pronounciation.  (i.e. 'though') and confuse my kids more than help them.  If it works though it'd be slick.

Comment: It works pretty well actually, and it is possible to spell them in different spellings to 'encourage' the engine to pronounce them properly.

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely familiar with that (forcing phoenetic spellings) - 'wich is wie I woud nott want et en eh sppeleng drel' :)

Comment: Even the speech synthesiser I had on my Apple IIe didn't need that much help :D

Besides, who says you have to display/expect the same string as what you're sending to the synthesiser?

Answer (score 2):

I've found [New Audio Components](http://symmetrica.net/newac/) to be quite good for Delphi.

Answer (score 2):

This component set looks promising though I've never used it myself. [AudioLab 3.1](http://www.mitov.com/html/audiolab.html) has both VCL components as well .NET 2.0 components which should allow you to use it whether you stay with developing your application in Delphi or move to C#. Finally, it appears to be Free for non-commercial use.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to look for Delphi Components

(Audio)
http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=167

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the TMediaPlayer that comes with Delphi (in the System Tab of the Palette)?
It can record and play wave files very easily

Answer (score 0):

I was also going to suggest [AudioLab](http://www.mitov.com/html/audiolab.html).